# Visual Studio 2012:error LNK1117: syntax error in option 'MAPINFO:LINES'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11

I put in the Linker Command line: `/MAPINFO:EXPORTS /MAPINFO:LINES`

and I get this error:

```
error LNK1117: syntax error in option 'MAPINFO:LINES'
```

How to turn-on `MAPINFO:LINES` in Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: What makes you believe that `/MAPINFO:LINES` option exists in nature? [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bha0yc3d.aspx) never mentions such a thing.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft dropped support for the `/MAPINFO:LINES` option in Visual Studio 2005. I don't think there's any simple replacement. You could write something using the dbghelp library to extract the line number information.