# No argument specified with option "/MAPINFO" , why?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I try to fix my previous company project on visual studio 2013, but when i try to build i have error like this

```
error LNK1146: no argument specified with option "/MAPINFO"
```

when i see on linker -> Command Line -> additional options,  i see this command:

```
 /MAPINFO:EXPORTS /MAPINFO  /MAPINFO:LINES
```

if i delete that command, i get success build my project,

what i asking is :

1. why compiler say no argument specified on that option ?
2. what /MAPINFO using for ?  (sorry i asking this cause i'm new on visual studio)
3. on my linker command line, is there any wrong command i write ?
4. if i delete this command does this effected on my project result ?

Thank you

PS: forgive my english

Comment: `/MAPINFO:LINES` is [no longer supported since VS 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25577460).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, /MAPINFO:LINES is no longer supported since VS2005. You could delete it.

If you need to use it, you may have a try to find a replacement of it. You can refer to the [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d1ae05e2-e2a2-435a-a4e5-35e42b3eadad/replacement-for-mapinofolines-in-visual-studio-2005?forum=vclanguage) below and consider using dbghelp library to do this.